# An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in

Tags: sql-server

```
select 
    * 
from sap_stockmaster 
where itemid=9893 
and salemrp=1034.00 
and salemrp in(
    select 
        salemrp 
    from sap_stockmaster 
    where SUM(stkqty)>0
) 
order by salemrp desc
```

I want record whose Sum of Quantity is greater than Zero but get the following error

> An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a
>   subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column
>   being aggregated is an outer reference.

Comment: Since you're quoting the error message verbatim, please explain what part of it it was that you didn't understand, because so far, all we can do is tell you that an aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.

Comment: change `where` to `having` and precede it with a `group by salemrp` on the subquery.

Comment: How can you get "Sum of Quantity" for a single record? Did you mean `where stkqty > 0` ?

Comment: Only select the columns you want, group by the columns that are not aggregated and put the `SUM(stkqty) > 0` in the `Having` clause.

Answer (score 3):

When filtering on aggregates you should use `having` and not `where`

```
select * 
from sap_stockmaster 
where itemid=9893 
and salemrp=1034.00 
and salemrp in (select salemrp 
    from sap_stockmaster 
    group by salemrp
    HAVING SUM(stkqty)>0) 
order by salemrp desc
```

Also this is probably more performant written as either a join or using EXISTS

```
-- example with Exists

SELECT * 
FROM sap_stockmaster ss1
WHERE itemid=9893 
AND salemrp=1034.00 
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 
    FROM sap_stockmaster ss2
    WHERE ss1.salemrp = ss2.salemrp
    GROUP BY ss2.salemrp
    HAVING SUM(ss2.stkqty)>0)
ORDER BY salemrp DESC
```

Comment: logically it seems a group by is needed too... but maybe not. and agree, exists would likely be faster.

Comment: not working... stkqty field is in same table i.e. in sap_stockmaster.

Comment: @Shail - ... which is why there are table aliases in the 2nd example that uses `EXISTS`.

Comment: I always seem to JOIN instead of using IN. I don't know which is faster the JOIN or EXISTS.

Comment: Still not working.... result not came properly. It shows whose stock is zero as well

Comment: @KeithL - Usually I find that all other things being equal Sql Server's execution plan is roughly the same either way you go (*between exists / join*).

Comment: select * from sap_stockmaster where sum(stkqty)>0 
and itemid=9893 and salemrp=1034.00 order by salemrp desc

Comment: but sum(stkqty) can't use like this... so what should I use?

Comment: @Shail - provide an [mcve] (read the link). You have to provide a DDL, sample data, and expected output. The queries I have included in my answer are correct. Why they don't work is probably user error, that is you have data values that you are not accounting for. What those are is anyones guess as we do not have your data in front of us. Without an [mcve] there is nothing anyone can do that does not have access to your PC.

Comment: May be you should filter on Item Id in the subquery and it will remove all the records where sum is zero.

SELECT * 
FROM sap_stockmaster ss1
WHERE itemid=9893 
AND salemrp=1034.00 
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 
    FROM sap_stockmaster ss2
    WHERE ss1.salemrp = ss2.salemrp
    AND ss2.itemid=ss1.salemrp
    GROUP BY ss2.salemrp
    HAVING SUM(ss2.stkqty)>0)
ORDER BY salemrp DESC

Comment: Issue not resolved.. it shows two records.... one with stock present and other is stock equal to zero.

Comment: Providing samples like @Igor mentioned would help.  For example if you sap_stockmaster has two rows, where both rows have same salemrp number, same item Id, and both rows have stkqty > 0 then both rows will show up. If this is not what you want, then please clearly state what you looking for. Do you want just unique list of salesmrp where they have multiple stkqty?

Comment: Yes, I have same item_id but salemrp has many rows with same salemrp or may different and stkqty is in both rows but I want only those rows whose sum(stkqty) is greater than zero.

Comment: Problem not solved, please let me know how to add sum(stkqty) in where condition while multiple select fieldnames